# predetermined possible values in a constructor

Tags: java, types, javadoc

Let's say I have a class that makes a ball. In the constructor, it accepts a `String` to indicate the kind of ball, but I only want it to accept certain values like: `"FOOTBALL"`, `"BASEBALL"`, or `"SOCCERBALL"`,  so that if I pass my class to another developer and they go to use it in Eclipse it prompts them as to the accepted value. How would I do that? I have no idea if there's a general technique I could use or what it might be called, so pointers to a tutorial or example would be welcome.

```
public class Ball {
    public Ball(String type){
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Ball class that defaults to FOOTBALL unless otherwise specified:

```
public class Ball {

    public static final int FOOTBALL = 0;
    public static final int BASEBALL = 1;
    public static final int SOCCERBALL = 2;

    int ball;

     public Ball(){
        this.ball = Ball.FOOTBALL;
     }// end constructor

    /**
     *  Class constructor.
     *
     * @param ball sets the ball value.<p>
     * <b>ball</b> must be one of the following: Ball.FOOTBALL, Ball.BASEBALL,
     *             Ball.SOCCERBALL.
     */
     public Ball(int ball){          
        setBall(ball);       
     }// end constructor

     public int getBall(){
         return ball;
     }// end getBall()

     public void setBall(int ball){          
         switch(ball){           
         case 1:
             this.ball = Ball.BASEBALL;
             break;
         case 2:
             this.ball = Ball.SOCCERBALL;
             break;
         default:
             this.ball = Ball.FOOTBALL;
             break;          
         }// end switch          
     }// end setBall()       
}// end class Ball
```

Edit:

I added doc comments for javadoc which I think is what you are looking for. Check this link out: [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: Suppose a subsequent developer (SD) starts using 3 for some FOOTBALL.  There is no problem until you (U) need to add GOLF to the list.  SD believes that U caused the problem by adding a new ball type.  U believe that SD caused the problem by using a nonstandard id.  Who is right?

Comment: If SD had read the javadocs then SD should have known better and should had only passed a static value such as Ball.FOOTBALL.

Comment: Enums are a lot cleaner and powerful than constants, I can't think of a single reason not to use them, can you?

Comment: Well, I can think of a couple of reasons why not to use enum's. For example: enum's can't extend other enum's since they all extend java.lang.Enum. Also, enum's are good to represent static/singleton objects but should never be used as value objects or have attributes that get set during usage. Read more here: http://ctotodevelopers.blogspot.com/2007/01/java-practice-when-not-to-use-enums.html

Comment: These shortcomings (others would call them features) are well known but constants can't be extended or set during usage either

Comment: ok guys.. here is the deal, i don't think any of these solutions is really what i am looking for.  Perhaps i am having a hard time articulating my desire.  From the main activity, when someone calls for an instance of  my Ball class, they would write 'Ball myBall = new Ball('  as soon as they open the new Ball with a "("  i would like one of those eclipse code hints to pop up saying that their choices are "FOOTBALL,SOCCERBALL, ect"  follow?

Comment: @erik I edited my response. I think what you want is comments for javadoc. See this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Comment: Ok, this is what i am looking for.. my confusion though is that it doesn't always show up?  how does one make it show up when they are calling the class?  I had it pop up once but not consistant?

Comment: It depends on whether the constructor/method is overloaded (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). My example above contains an overloaded constructor. Only one of the constructors has javadoc comments. You can add javadoc comments to the first constructor and add @see to reference the overloaded constructor. Here's another useful link on javadocs: http://www.ehow.com/how_2094987_create-javadoc-commenting.html. I should add that you want to hover the cursor over the constructor/method to get the tips/hints in Eclipse.

Answer (score 8):

You could use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a string, like below. Enums are very powerful so you could for example add a bounce method to each ball type and each ball type would know how they are supposed to bounce (cf link above for more info / examples). That also solves your problem of restricting values. If you don't create a MEATBALL type in your enum, nobody can pass a meat ball as a type for your constructor.

```
public enum BallType {
     FOOTBALL,
     BASEBALL,
     SOCCERBALL;
}

public Ball(BallType type) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about declaring public static constants in your class? For example, something like:

public static final String BALL_FOOTBALL="FOOTBALL";
...

If you throw an exception when the ball type is wrong, it will force the other developer to use one of the predefined constants.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: It won't really force the other developer to use one of the predefined constants.  It will compile just fine and will only fail at runtime.  Then the user will get to find out that the developer typed "FootBall" when "FOOTBALL" should have been typed.  It is much better to find these things out at compile time.  The compiler (unlike the user) will not badmouth you to everyone.  So let it as much as possible discover your mistakes.